# Bash Script to find the bad and good of the mahcine

Tags: bash, shell-script, monitoring

I'm trying to create a bash script that at a certain time finds me a "bad", which is associated with a machine and a service.

It turns out that from that time on I wanted to find the respective "good" for that machine and that service.

So far everything more or less. The question is that I can have at the same time or in the following different services and different machines with a "bad" and I needed to find the "good" of the respective one at the same time.

In addition, if the bad persists for 5 minutes, I would like to receive an alert

I give example:

```
Date: Dec 16 2022 12:38:18 | State: bad | Service: xpto | Machine: Machine1
Date: Dec 16 2022 12:38:18 | State: bad | Service: xpto | Machine: Machine2
Date: Dec 16 2022 12:38:18 | State: bad | Service: xpto2 | Machine: Machine3
Date: Dec 16 2022 12:38:18 | State: good | Service: xpto | Machine: Machine1 <- solved
Date: Dec 16 2022 12:38:20 | State: good | Service: xpto | Machine: Machine2 <- solved
Date: Dec 16 2022 12:38:18 | State: bad | Service: xpto2 | Machine: Machine3 <- again bad
Date: Dec 16 2022 12:39:24 | State: bad | Service: xpto2 | Machine: Machine3 <- again bad
Date: Dec 16 2022 12:43:18 | State: bad | Service: xpto2 | Machine: Machine3 <- more 5 min -> alert
```

This with multiple machines and services at the same time.

Initially I try to copy only the bad to a file and after find the good corresponding, but when I have a lot machines and services, and this are differents doesn't work for me.

Any master who can help me on this topic?

Comment: What have you searched, tried, and what fails ?

Comment: I decided to break the problem into parts, but I'm not seeing success.
I started by looking for all the "bad" and sending them to a file.

`cat alerts.log | grep bad >> bad_logs`

and then I was trying to get the date, server and service variables and I wanted to go to the alerts.log file to see if there was a "good" from that date, but for all machines and servers.

`awk -F'|' '{print $1,$3,$4}' bad_logs`

am i thinking right, or should i not go this way?